# The library is compiled without QT support in function 'displayOverlay' on mac

Tags: macos, qt, opencv

While running this code,

```
# Add a trackbar
import cv2 as cv

def trackbar(x):
    """Trackbar callback function."""
  text = f'Trackbar: {x}'
  cv.displayOverlay('window', text, 1000)
  cv.imshow('window', img)

img = cv.imread('messi.jpg', cv.IMREAD_COLOR)
cv.imshow('window', img)
cv.createTrackbar('x', 'window', 100, 255, trackbar)

cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

I came across this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/derteck/PycharmProjects/trab3/window_size.py", line 42, in trackbar
    cv.displayOverlay('window', text, 1000)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) /Users/runner/work/opencv-python/opencv- 
python/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:1196: error: (-213:The function/feature 
is not implemented) The library is compiled without QT support in function 
'displayOverlay'
```

I'm on Mac, I have seen possible solutions for windows but they involved re-installing.
Thank you.

Comment: you can only use [qt extras](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/d46/group__highgui__qt.html)   **IF** you built your cv2 locally, with a qt sdk installed. for now, you have to go without the `displayOverlay`

Comment: official binary distributions of OpenCV, these days, come without the Qt dependency. maybe you can find a build that does use Qt? -- to replicate this overlay effect, you'd have to use `putText` and watch the time to know when to stop drawing the message (overlay fades/disappears after a moment). -- or simply `print` to the console (python function).